# OleDb data reader issue

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net, oledb

I have a vb.net program that uses `MySQL` database. Now I changed the database into `Microsoft Access 2010`. I changed all necessary settings like connection preference, commands etc.

The issue is: I have got an error around

> mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader

and it generates an error:

> Error 1   Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' cannot be converted to 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.OleDb.OleDbDataReader'

The entire code is:

```
 Public Sub showAlarm()
        Try
            Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connection)
            Dim myadapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            conn.Open()
            Dim sqlquery = "select * from alarm"
            Dim mycommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            mycommand.Connection = conn
            mycommand.CommandText = sqlquery
            myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
            Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
            mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader
            'If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            '    MsgBox("Data Not Found")
            '    TextBox1.Clear()
            'Else
            mydata.Read()
            TextBox1.Text = mydata.Item("subhi")
            TextBox2.Text = mydata.Item("zuhur")
            TextBox3.Text = mydata.Item("aser")
            TextBox4.Text = mydata.Item("megrib")
            TextBox5.Text = mydata.Item("isha")
            'End If
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("There is a problem with your connection!")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes you right bro. Now I have edited my question as brief as possible with entire code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `mycommand` is a `OleDbCommand` `mycommand.ExecuteReader` returns a `OleDbDataReader` but `mydata` is a `MySqlDataReader`. So change `mydata` to be also a `OleDbDataReader`.

```
Dim mydata As OleDbDataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Side-note: you should use the `Using`-statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed:

```
Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connection)
    Using mycommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from alarm", conn)
        conn.Open()
        Using mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
            If mydata.Read Then
                ' ... '
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks bro, the problem is fixed.